# Bug While Executing the setPositiveButton in the Dialog Box Builder?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I am trying to write a dialog box in my app . The problem is when i click the OK (SetPositiveButton) it is showing the following **Runtime Error**

*E/AndroidRuntime(702): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException*

If i am trying to execute the commented lines in the below code , But it works fine in the onClick but showing some Kind of Bug for setPositiveButton

```
   @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id){

 case ONCLICK_EXTRAS:
     return new AlertDialog.Builder(AcricklayoutActivity.this)
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
     .setTitle("Extras")
     .setSingleChoiceItems(R.array.extras, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.extras);
             value = items[which];
             Log.v("this",String.valueOf(which)+items[which]);
         }
     })
     .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.extras);
            //text.setText(items[which]);
            // Log.v("this",String.valueOf(which)+items[which]);

         }
     })
     .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


         }
     })
    .create();
```

I will explain my code here

1. I am trying to use an String array from the Resource/values file to populate my AlertDialogbox ,
2. And Storing that into the Static String variable **value**

**it works fine till the positive button click** of the dialog activity after that app gets crashed.. Can anyone Help me in this issue ???

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Are you sure of the value of `which` in your setPositiveButton method? and that this value DO EXIST in the String[] ?

Comment: @Sephy: yeah i am sure... I checked with the debugger and also with Logcat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
```

This `which` in this method tells the button which was clicked, and you should not be using it as index for your arrays. `which` can be any of these:

```
Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE; (value=-2)

Dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL;  (value=-3)

Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE   (value=-1)
```

Naturally if you use it for getting values from array, it will give you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: i am not getting your answer..!! which returns the int value between 0 to n-1 , where the array contains n elements.. right ??
what u are trying to say ?? can u explain..

Comment: "which" will return which button on dialog was clicked. its values may be -1, -2 or -3 depending on whether you clicked positive, negative, or neutral button.

Comment: fine..i will try... to find an another way to this

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't seem to be with the code for your button, just simply the code withing that is run on click. This code:

```
String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.extras);
value = items[which];
Log.v("this",String.valueOf(which)+items[which]);
```

It seems the problem is that your String array doesn't have a value at the position `which`.

Print out your values, and the integer (named `which`) to verify that the value in that position doesn't exist. Then modify your code according to your desired result.

Comment: I tried as you said but while the initialization of string array itself the application is getting crashed... But i dont know why its not getting initialized alone in setPositiveButton()...??? and working fine in onClick()

Comment: So you're saying that this line is crashing the app?:

String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.extras);

Because it seems like it's when you're trying to get a value from the array, hence the IndexOutOfBoundsException